# nginx try_files and index not performing as expected

Tags: file, nginx

```
location /social {
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri /social/index.php;
}
```

When a user hits up a directory, it needs to run the local ./index.php
So far, when people hit up /social/  it runs index.php
When the user visits all unknown URLs, they get /social/index.php

However, when a user vists /social/subdir/  and there is a /social/subdir/index.php, it still runs /social/index.php.  I need it to run /social/subdir/index.php

if I change the config to:

```
location /social {
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/index.php /social/index.php;
}
```

Then nginx serves up the CONTENT of social/subdir/index.php as content-type: octet/stream.

I thought index index.php would look for the paths index file.

php rendering block:

```
location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

    expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content        
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a php handling block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main issue is that you didn't use `http://` before `127.0.0.1:9000` , also make sure that your php uses port 9000 not a sock file, otherwise you change the `fastcgi_pass` to unix socket.

Here's my simplified config.

Remove the `index index.php` from the `/social` block if it's the same value in the `server` block.

```
location /social {
    # index index.php; # remove if not needed
    try_files $uri $uri/ /social/index.php;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: all 4 apps running on this server used index index.php;  I moved the declaration to the server block, out of the app level block and it worked again. Had to be done in conjunction with removing the @handler by IfIsEvil

Answer (score 1):

First remove the index.php from the try_files directive so it will look like this

```
location /social {
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /social/index.php =404;
}
```

Also make sure that no other location block catches the /social/subdir/ request.

Lastly (irrelevant to your question, but very important) remove this line

```
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
```

It is totally redundant and evil. `try_files` does not miss 404s. Have a look at this for more info [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)

Comment: yeah... someone in marketing learned about php so to make all their url's more powerful, they added it to links like /get/offer/.php so I have to catch and trim them off. Just because it hits the location .php block doesn't mean it actually was php.

try_files $uri $uri/ /social/index.php =404; results in "/social/index.php" executing instead of "/social/subdir/index.php"

Comment: Also make sure that no other location block catches the /social/subdir/ request. ... 
An app that was removed still contained this in the config. location @handler {   rewrite / /index.php;  } and it cause some kind of interference